# Unit testing a void method with Redis async command in java

Tags: java, asynchronous, junit, redis, lettuce

I'm trying to write a unit test for the following function.

**responseHandler** and **ErrorHandler** are both methods that are passes using the Command Pattern
and are used to continue the program's flow.
**futureCommand** is a lettuce object (Redis implementation in java).
I'm having difficulties with how to test this method since is both using a future and does not return anything.

```
public void getOfferData(EventRequestContext<? extends BaseEvent> ctx, int offerId, ResponseHandler<T1Offer> responseHandler,
        ErrorHandler<Throwable> errorHandler) throws Exception {
    String redisKey = keyPrefix + offerId;
    RedisFuture<List<String>> futureCommand = connectionWrapper.getHashValues(redisKey, getRequiredParams());
    futureCommand.thenAccept(valuesList -> {
        TrackerScheduler.processT1GenreicPool.execute(ctx, () -> {
            Map<String, String> resultMap = reconstructMapValues(valuesList, getRequiredParams(), redisKey, ctx);
            T1Offer offerData;
            if(!resultMap.isEmpty()) {
                offerData = new T1Offer(resultMap);
            } else {
                offerData = new T1Offer();
            }
            if(!offerData.isValid()) {
                errorHandler.onError(new Exception("Invalid fields in offerData"));
            } else {
                responseHandler.onResponse(offerData);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

My best attempt was to send the assertion using the **`responseHandler`** method like this:

```
@Test
public void getOfferData_offerFullData_parseSuccess() throws Exception {
    T1ClickOfferDao.instance.getOfferData(null, Integer.parseInt(OFF_ID), resultOffer -> { 
        Assert.assertEquals("", resultOffer.getActivationDate());
    }, error -> {
    });
}
```

but the Test context is finished before the future is evaluated. And even if I `Threas.sleep` for a second - the assertion does not affect the test result.

Comment: "does not return anything" have you considered making it return the future?

Comment: Returning the future will pass the logic in "thenAccept()" to the calling method, same problem different place.

Comment: Ok, so... Return the result of `futureCommand.thenAccept(...).toCompleteableFuture()`?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
@Test
public void getOfferData_offerFullData_parseSuccess() throws Exception {
    final String lock = new String("lock");
    T1ClickOfferDao.instance.getOfferData(null, Integer.parseInt(OFF_ID), resultOffer -> { 
        Assert.assertEquals("", resultOffer.getActivationDate());
        synchronized(lock){
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }, error -> {
    });
    synchronized(lock){
        try{ 
            lock.wait(1000*2); 
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            fail("Timeout");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have any success with it?

Comment: Yes, eventually did something like the example above with locking and it works well. seems to be the only way.